# why doesn't border-box work on inline-block element?

Tags: html, css

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L5jchnpm/

I have ran into problem, i was under impression that `display: inline-block` makes elements behave as inline and block elements.

And that `box-sizing: border-box`, makes block elements width to compensate for border's width however this doesn't seem to be the case for `inline-block`.

border width is simply not included.

What is a workaround for this, and any reason why it's like this.

code

```
<ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>about</li>
    <li>work</li>
    <li>portfolio</li>
    <li>contact</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul {
    overflow: auto;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;

}

li:hover {
    border: 5px solid;
}
```

Comment: Since you're talking about an inline-block the most likely cause is that the inline-block doesn't actually have a set width - it's just shrinking to fit its contents. Box sizing isn't going to affect how it calculates its content box - it still needs to fit its contents at minimum - so it doesn't make sense to have a workaround in that particular case.

Comment: Show code and / or screenshot?

Comment: Please add you code?.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/6jh3tb7z/)

Comment: ok code added, please check it out

Comment: `box-sizing` determines how an explicit `height` or `width` is treated. You don't have `height` nor `width`, so `box-sizing` makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The work around: use outline instead of border, set a `margin` value to the `li` CSS so that they won't react weird when you hover over them, something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6v5f0cqf/1/):

```
li{
    outline: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
  }
li:hover {
    outline: 5px solid;
}
```